# Ampersand shows as $amp; in global navigation

Tags: navigation

Just a very quick question, hopefully someone can help:

**On my global navigation, any items that have an & symbol in them display as the full &** (actually displayed on the page, not in the code) which is quite bizarre. **On the side navigation it looks just fine.**

So sorry to ask a fairly trivial question, but honestly I'm very (very!!!) new to Sharepoint and haven't touched ASP before, and find it hard to work out exactly where this is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special characters in the menu probably have to be escaped.

I am not sure if this is what you need, but please check this link

http://www.devcow.com/blogs/adnrg/archive/2007/12/14/sharepoint-escape-characters-extended.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  While not a overall fix, I have managed to fix this on each `dispform.aspx` by editing the page and adding a content editor web part (Below the dispform webpart) and adding the following javascript.

Solution / Workaround:
 I have added a content editor webpart to the dispform of the pages that are affected. Which include some javascript to change the html to show up as text instead of values of text.

```
 // Fix for HTML encoded choice field value on display form
 function registerChoiceFieldTemplateOverrides() {
 var choiceFieldContextOverride = {};
 choiceFieldContextOverride.Templates = {};
 choiceFieldContextOverride.Templates.Fields = {
 'Choice': {
 // The important bit: Change the display form template to the one that doesn't encode the value again. The original function that was used is: SPField_FormDisplay_Default 'DisplayForm': window.SPField_FormDisplay_DefaultNoEncode,
 },
 };
 window.SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(choiceFieldContextOverride);
 }
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerChoiceFieldTemplateOverrides, 'clientforms.js');
```